# Where the "g_debug" output in GDM source code?

Tags: gnome, gdm

I want to know how gdm works, so I read the gdm source code. I saw a lot of `g_debug` output in the source code like this:

```c
case SIGUSR1:
            g_debug ("Got USR1 signal");
            /* FIXME:
             * Play with log levels or something
             */
            ret = TRUE;

            gdm_log_toggle_debug ();

            break;
```

But I want to know where I can find the `g_debug` output.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `G_DEBUG` environment variable to make GLib print out the debugging information.

Check the values in the documentation for [Running and Debugging GLib Applications](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Fedora 20, you can modify the gdm configuration file, `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` then add the following.

```
[debug]
Enable=True
Gesture=True
```

Then you can view the logs by typing `journalctl -lr` in the terminal.